# Multiple choice answers - how to show correct and incorrect answer

Tags: selection, choices, quiz

I have a multiple choice quiz, where the user is given feedback, I need to show - their choice and if they were correct or not.

[image]

In this example the question was 'What is the capital of Germany'. I have tried lots of variations but have not really got something that works.

I need to show

- the answer they picked
- if it was correct or not
- the right answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Try saving the icons for the results, and use visual distinction to show their selection.

You can separate the result and feedback right below the choices (with their selection).

The feedback can use 2 levels of visual distinction: color and icon. For incorrect answers, show them the correct answer in close proximity to the feedback.

[image]

Comment: I like this answer - they way I was trying to do it without the clarification was a bit clumsy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With motion and deletion.
Left to right movement for a negative choice.
Top to bottom movement for a positive choice.
And then: text-decoration: line-through for wrong answers.